# Writes file directly to an HTTP response output stream (without using any Download Managers like IDM)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm going to write a file directly to an HTTP response, it works when I use Download Manager on my PC, but after disable download manager it doesn't work.

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(FilePath)
context.Response.ClearContent();
context.Response.ClearHeaders();
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name +";");
context.Response.ContentType = "application/x-zip-compressed";
context.Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
```

[Response on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9DA4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Call `context.Response.Flush` or `context.Response.End`

**Response.Flush**

Forces all currently buffered output to be sent to the client. Can be called multiple times during requests.

**Response.End**

Sends all currently buffered output to the client and stops execution.